# xpath: selecting all siblings without given element?

Tags: html, xpath

```
<html> 
<body> 
<div id="products"> 
<h1>text1</h1> <b> description1 </b> <i>foo</i>
<h1>text2</h1> <b> description2 </b> 
<h1>text3</h1> 
<h1>text4</h1> <b> description4 </b> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

`//h1[not(following-sibling::*[1][self::b])]` selects the `text3` heading.

`<i>foo</i>` can be in any position ! It may not always be in the position described above.

I want to select the `h1` element which doesn't have `foo`, so I should get

```
text2,text3,text4
```

Comment: Why does `<h1>text1</h1>` *have* `<i>foo</i>` ? There is no hierarchical relation between them. The only thing you could say is to get all `<h1>` elements after `<i>foo</i>`. (Besides that, you HTML is not 100% valid, afaik heading elements are not allowed in `div` elements.)

Comment: @Felix: Actually, this is *valid* HTML. I think you have mistakenly mixed the `div` with the `p` tag, *which* can not contain `h1` (but div can).

Comment: +1 Good question. I don't know why are the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath query:

`//h1[following-sibling::h1/following-sibling::i] | //h1[preceding-sibling::i]`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comment, what you could do is this:

```
//i[contains(.,'foo')]/following-sibling::h1
```

or even

```
//*[contains(.,'foo')]/following-sibling::h1
```

**Update:** If you consider the preceding `h1` as the one that "contains" `foo`, you could do this:

```
//*[contains(., 'foo')]/(following-sibling::h1 | remove(preceding-sibling::h1, 1)))
```

this works for e.g.

```
<h1>text1</h1> <b> description1 </b> 
<h1>text2</h1> <b> description2 </b> <i>foo</i>
<h1>text3</h1> 
<h1>text4</h1> <b> description4 </b>
```

Comment: the reason is that the i could be in any of those positions....it is not always in the first row.

Comment: `remove` it's not valid XPath function.

Comment: @Alejandro: It is defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-remove. Maybe it is XPath 2.0. Why should it not be valid? Anyway, similar functionality can be achieved with `preceding-sibling::h1[1]/preceding-sibling::h1`

Comment: You are right. I should say it's not valid XPath 1.0. By the way, in XPath 1.0 the expression should be `preceding-sibling::h1[position()!=1]`. Do note that in the `remove()` call you are removing the last one in reverse document order, because the preceding sequence it's calculated first and then returned in document order.

Comment: @Alejandro: I'm not sure about the sequence order. It worked for me with my test example, but unfortunately I have not so much insight in which order the elements are returned...